# Суммирование двух векторов

Tags: ассемблер

Здравствуйте!

Знаю что это по крайней мере некрасиво просить других делать работу за тебя, но времени в обрез и до завтрашнего утра у меня нету шансов разобраться с этим...

Итак, ассемблер, `tasm`.

Даны 2 вектора, такого вида:

```
n1 dw 6,2,1,3,1,1             
n2 dw 2,1,2,1,4,3
```

нужно написать код, который суммирует попарно элементы этих 2 векторов, а результат записывает в 3 вектор.

то есть на экран нужно вывести что-то вроде:

```
n3 8, 3, 3, 4, 5, 4
```

Помогите хотя бы наброском...

Comment: Набросок, увы, не получился - здесь всё настолько просто, что непонятно, как с такой элементарной вещью можно не разобраться, это же азы, букварь...

Comment: Хмм, у вас действительно выглядит очень просто код...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
.DATA
    n1 dw 6,2,1,3,1,1 
    n2 dw 2,1,2,1,4,3
    n3 dw 0,0,0,0,0,0

.CODE
    lea ebx, n1
    lea edx, n2
    lea edi, n3
    mov ecx, 6
    push ds ; для stosw
    pop es
r:  
    mov ax, [ebx]
    add ax, [edx] ; переполнение не отслеживаем
    stosw
    add ebx, 2 ; inc ebx/inc ebx
    add edx, 2 ; inc edx/inc edx
    loop r
```

Comment: Никак не могу его скомпилировать, добавил начальные
.model small
.stack 100h

и в конце 

end

А компилятор ругается про unexpected end of file encountered

также не могу понять как компьютер выйдет из цикла loop r?

Comment: Тогда уж и .386 в начало не помешает. А насчёт loop - учебники читать не пробовали, раз уж это явно учебное задание? Если с бумажными совсем туго, то и онлайн есть, [да вот хотя бы](http://www.firststeps.ru/asm/r.php?46).